# How can I correctly implement probability in Java?

Tags: java, probability

I seem to have a problem I don't know why its happening its starting to look like witchcraft. This is the way I tried to implement probability:

```java
int odd = (int)(100.0 * Math.random()); //Number between 1 and 100
if(odd<=50){ //50% chance
   System.out.println("Lucky");
}
```

However, when I place it like this odd is ALWAYS inferior to 50, if I change the "<" to a ">" it ALWAYS generates number bigger than 50, which makes as the if statement happens every time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your described behavior. I get a uniform distrubition of random values between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive). Nitpick: you actually want `<` and not `<=`, otherwise your result will be slightly skewed

Comment: Are you sure that it is ALWAYS,  how often have you tested it?

Comment: Ive tested it about 12 times in a for loop so... many times

Comment: Have you compiled the new code? You might be running an old executable.

Comment: I have restarded fully my computer and it seems my bad luck is gone?! Made 2 more tests now i get a similar result as Belkov Dmytro . Maybe you are right @Ted Klein Bergamn  or maybe its witchcraft at this point i dont know

Comment: If you are only printing out `odd` when it is less than 50, you will only see values less than 50. The same is if you are printing when `odd` is greater than 50. If this is what you are doing, then yes, you will see that it ALWAYS shows that `odd` is less than 50 or greater than 50.

Comment: Could you show us the complete code, including the loop?

Comment: Another thing you could do to help debug this is to print the numeric value of odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just had bad luck or whatever, so you got 10 or 100 times depending on how often you tested it, a larger or smaller number.  Because your code works, I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is running well for me, and I do not find something wrong in your code. It may just generated many random numbers in a row that satisfied the statement.

Comment: I'm an unlucky fellow then ahhaha Ive made more than a few tests

Comment: @Phil Have you tried it again? And if yes, what were the results?

Comment: Been on another 4 tries,i think I'm cursed. I gonna try restarting the whole damn thing and pray it works well

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand which problem did you have. I tried this code:

```
int b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <100000;i++){
        int odd = (int) (100.0 * Math.random()); //Number between 1 and 100
        if (odd < 50) { //50% chance
            System.out.println("Lucky");
            b++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unlucky");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Lucky tries : " + b);
    System.out.println("Unlucky tries : " + (100000 - b));
}
```

And it gave me the following result

```
Lucky tries : 50060
Unlucky tries : 49940
```